# in typescript Repeating the data from one row to other

Tags: arrays, typescript

I Have an array of object in react typescript. On each row I have repeat button I want to copy the data from the current row and paste it to all other remaining rows.
[image]

I need to write a function for my react typescript component.
In the picture you can see there is rpt button, for example if I have 5 rows and I click the rpt button on the 3rd row it takes the year and option value and insert into 4th and 5th row.
If I click the rpt button on 4th row then it copies the year and option value from the 4th row and insert into to 5th.

```
const repeatData = (index: number) => {
setSubjects((s) => {
  const newState = [...subjects];
  const clickedRow = { ...subjects[index] };
  index = index + 1;
  while (index < subjects.length) {
    const currentRow = { ...subjects[index] };
    currentRow.Type = clickedRow.Type;
    currentRow.Year = clickedRow.Year;
    currentRow.Option = clickedRow.Option;
    newState.splice(index, 1, currentRow);
  }
  return newState;
});
```

};

```
  const repeatData = (event: SyntheticEvent, index: number) => {
setSubjects((s) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  const newState = [...subjects];
  const clickedRow = { ...subjects[index] };
  while (index < subjects.length) {
    const currentRow = { ...subjects[index] };
    index = index + 1;
    currentRow.Type = clickedRow.Type;
    currentRow.Option = clickedRow.Option;
    currentRow.Year = clickedRow.Year;
    newState.splice(index, 1, currentRow);
  }
  return newState;
});
```

};

Comment: what have you tried? can you show us your code?

Comment: I have added my function code above please have a look.

Comment: The second block of code is working fine. I just want to check if there is some more efficient way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

```
  const repeatData = (event: SyntheticEvent, index: number) => {
setSubjects((s) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  const newState = [...subjects];
  const clickedRow = { ...subjects[index] };
  while (index < subjects.length) {
    const currentRow = { ...subjects[index] };
    index = index + 1;
    currentRow.Type = clickedRow.Type;
    currentRow.Option = clickedRow.Option;
    currentRow.Year = clickedRow.Year;
    newState.splice(index, 1, currentRow);
  }
  return newState;
});
```

};

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.